# How to use Element.findall() to search for a tag and print its value

Tags: python

I decided to venture with `python v2.6.6` among other choices to locate and print specific `tag` within `xml` file. I ended up having multiple `for..loop` which I was not pleased with I thought there may be a better way.

I searched through in here and it seems like `Element.findall()` was promising but empty value is printed. Here is the sample file (`test.xml`).

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<parent>
   <first>
        <a>123</a>
        <b>abc</b>                
        <c>
          <d>987</d>
          <e>
            <f>xxx</f>
            <f>yyy</f>
            <f>zzz</f>
          </e>
         </c>
    </first>
    <second>
         <a>456</a>
         <b>efg</b>             
         <c>
          <d>345</d>
          <e>
            <f>ttt</f>
            <f>hhh</f>
            <f>www</f>
          </e>
         </c>
     </second>
</parent>
```

My goal is hoping to `identify` and `print` value of the tag `<d>` and multiple `<f>`.

Here is my 1st attempt with `findall()` to find the tag `<b>` but empty value is printed..

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

root = ET.parse('test.xml').getroot()
b_tag = root.findall('first/b')
print b_tag
```

Can someone experienced in `python` guide me what I did wrong so that I could have better understanding of how to use that `api`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works perfectly with `b_tag`, you only need to use the `.text` field. So, here is all info inside `<d>` and `<f>` that you wanted:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

root = ET.parse('test.xml').getroot()
d_tags = root.findall('./*/c/d')
print([t.text for t in d_tags])
# ['987', '345']

f_tags = root.findall('./*/c/e/f')
print([t.text for t in f_tags])
# ['xxx', 'yyy', 'zzz', 'ttt', 'hhh', 'www']
```

Comment: I appreciate your time looking into my problem. Bear with me, I tried `print b_tag.text` but it threw `list object has no attribute text`. I am goodling it now but if you have a thought ^ err, would you let me know? Ty!

Comment: yes, because `b_tag` is a list... try `b_tag[0].text`