# Looking for syntax to traverse all the nested tags in ElementTree.findall() in python

Tags: python, xml

Plz bear with me I am struggling with `xml` and `ElementTree` from `python`. I have posted a question: [How to use Element.findall() to search for a tag and print its value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62044014/how-to-use-element-findall-to-search-for-a-tag-and-print-its-value/62044237#62044237) and provided solution worked fine however later I realized that `namespace` was registered on `<parent>` tag. I had no idea how that piece of data would change the game plan.

```
<parent xmlns="http://xmlns.test.com/parent" version="1">
```

Having `namespace`, this `findall('./*/c/d')` no longer finds nested `tag` (i.e. `c/d`). Reading more threads in here I realized that I have to prepend with `namespace` like this.

```
def search(root, wordToSearch):
  tags = root.findall('{http://xmlns.test.com/parent}first')
  print tags
```

Above code will find `<first>` tag for sure however I am hoping to have `catch all` path something like (`./*/c/d`) that would traverse `<first>` then `<second>` tag.

My concern is `xml` could have `third or even more` tag under `<parent>` in the future. Is there way I can pull this off without using `lxml` library? Btw - I have both python `2.6.6` and `2.7.18` in `rhel` server I am running the script.

[update]

Fortunately I was able to find a solution with `ElementTree 1.3`.

```
def search(root, wordToSearch):
   for child in root: # child represents first and second tag
     el = child.tag.split('}', 1)[1] # Remove namespace
     el_path = 'xmlns:{0}/xmlns:c/xmlns:d'.format(el)
     target_tags = root.findall(el_path, namespaces={'xmlns': 'http://...'})
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you?

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def get_texts(root, tag_name):
    return [tag.get_text() for tag in root.find_all(tag_name)]

soup = BeautifulSoup(open('test.xml').read(), features="lxml")
print(get_texts(soup, 'd'))
print(get_texts(soup, 'f'))
```

Output:

```
['987', '345']
['xxx', 'yyy', 'zzz', 'ttt', 'hhh', 'www']
```

Here's the package: https://pypi.org/project/beautifulsoup4/